# terminationGracePeriodSeconds default value is 45 second

Tags: kubernetes, deployment

We have noticed that after applying deployment kubernetes sets `terminationGracePeriodSeconds` default value to 45 seconds in one of the deployments, all deployments are applied without specifying `terminationGracePeriodSeconds` parameter and after roll out it should set default value to 30 seconds, but in only one it sets 45 seconds.
Cluster is in Azure
AKS version 1.15.11
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MEw6i.png)
Does any one experience or noticed such behavior.
I have tried to search but couldn't find any article related to this

Regards,
Vahe

Comment: If you recreate the pods the situation is the same? Could you add your deployment yaml if possible? I wouldn't worry much about that because if you need to have 30s in all of them then you can set it in your deployment.

Comment: sorry for late answer, yes situation is the same when recreating pods.
I know that we can define in deployment and set desired value we want, it was just strange for me that we didn't define and deployments applies default value 45s

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1W7CqyJxeYZENKih5fgik3Bu8NIddJmdp/view?usp=sharing